# Detect song ending in YTPlayer View in iOS

Tags: ios, youtubeplayer

I have used YTPlayer View to play song using videoID, now i want to detect the current song ending state, i have used a delegate but it isn't catching it.How i can detect when the song is finish so that i could play next song. This is my code,

```
func playerView(playerView: YTPlayerView!, didChangeToState state: YTPlayerState)
{
    switch (state) {
    case YTPlayerState.playing:
        print("Started playback");
        break;
    case YTPlayerState.paused:
        print("Paused playback");
        break;
    case YTPlayerState.ended:
        print("Ended playback");
        self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1

        let videoId = playListArray[selectedIndex].videoId
        self.songView.load(withVideoId: videoId!, playerVars: playerVars)
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Have used this delegate also,`YTPlayerViewDelegate`. But it isn't coming inside end state.

Comment: try this on this on your play state --> get the overall duration of video and  current time video and subtract the current time in overall duration, you get the elapsed time in here add your condition,

Comment: Bro, it is not even catching play state and pause state. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: can you add some additional code, your delegate is called or not

Comment: add this delegate and check once `didPlayTime`

Comment: I have called delegate on YTplayerView outlet like this songView.delegate = self . @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: add some additional code, is this possible to attach your project, its easy to evoluate

Comment: which code? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: related to YTplayerView

Comment: Just have this code in my VC. @Anbu.Karthik